# How to change widgets from one theme to another theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, widget, widget-instance

I am having magento site with more then 80 widgets, now i am looking  to change theme , with new package name and theme(here i have two themes for mobile and desktop). what is the best way to copy widgets to current two themes?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best idea is 
change theme programatically
getting all widget using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->getCollection();
```

than change theme whatever you want

Comment: Thx bro, i followed same way what you updated. i have changed some other things as my requirement.

Comment: please accept my answer if it useful for you

Comment: How can I get all widget instances in Magento 2? I guess the answer is for Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
//for specific widgets , use array
//use Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->getCollection(); for all widgets
$widgets=[1105,1103,1119,1147,537,1136,1095,1096];
foreach($widgets as $widget)
{
  echo "<br>=================================".$widget;
  $widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($widget);
  $data=$widget->getData();
  $data['package_theme']='pkg/theme';
  unset($data['instance_id']);//for creating keep this one , for update comment this line
  $new_page_groups = array();
  foreach($data['page_groups'] as $group) {
      $page_group_name = $group['page_group']; // i.e. 'anchor_categories', 'simple_products'
      $new_group = array(
          'page_group' => $page_group_name,
           $page_group_name => array(
               'page_id' => $group['page_id'],
               'layout_handle' => $group['layout_handle'],
               'entities' => $group['entities'],
               'for' => $group['page_for'],
               'block' => $group['block_reference'],
               'template' => $group['page_template'],
           )
      );
      $new_page_groups[] = $new_group;
  }
    $data['page_groups'] = $new_page_groups;
    $newWidgetinstance = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->setData($data)->save();
    print_r($newWidgetinstance->getData());
}
```

Comment: Does this work also in Magento 2?